# Scraping dividends from dividend.com with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape dividends from dividend.com, here is my script:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.dividend.com/ex-dividend-dates.php?from_filter=yes&ex_div_date_min=2018-01-11&ex_div_date_max=2018-01-11&common_shares=on&preferred_shares=on&adrs=on&etns=on&funds=on&notes=on&etfs=on&reits=on'

page = requests.get(url)
page_content = page.content

with open('page_content.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(page_content))
    f.close()
```

I save the result into text file, and I'm interested in the blocks that look like in the uploaded picture,

[html block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSN8O.png)

In the file, there are many blocks of this one, I want to save these blocks into a list of dictionaries, each dictionary should contain the data of one block, and should look like below,

{
'Stock Symbol': 'MFO',
'Company Name': 'MFA Financial Inc. 8% Sr. Notes due 2042',
'DARS™ Rating': '',
'Ex-Div Date': '2018-01-11',
'Pay Date': '2018-01-16',
'Div Payout': '0.50',
'Qualified Dividend?': 'No',
'Stock Price': '$26.04',
'Yield': '7.68%',
}

Please help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use specific libs like `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the data of that table is generated dynamically, you have to gatecrash with selenium to grab what you want. Here is a script which is written combining BeautifulSoup and selenium to serve the purpose:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.dividend.com/ex-dividend-dates.php?from_filter=yes&ex_div_date_min=2018-01-11&ex_div_date_max=2018-01-11&common_shares=on&preferred_shares=on&adrs=on&etns=on&funds=on&notes=on&etfs=on&reits=on")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
driver.quit()
table = soup.select("table#ex-dividend-dates")[0]
list_row =[[tab_d.text.strip().replace("\n","") for tab_d in item.select('th,td')]
            for item in table.select('tr')]

for data in list_row[:2]:
    print(' '.join(data))
```

Here is the result:

```
Stock Symbol Company Name DARS™ Rating Ex-Div Date Pay Date Div Payout Qualified Dividend? Stock Price Yield
MFO MFA Financial Inc. 8% Sr. Notes due 2042  2018-01-11 2018-01-16 0.50 No $26.04 7.68%
```